# ComponentWillMount doesn't set the state React JS

Tags: reactjs

Why this isn't working :

```
class Slider extends React.Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            top : 0,
            responsiveImg : ""
        };
    }

    componentWillMount(){
        const bodyWidth = window.innerWidth;
        const responsiveSliderImg = "responsiveSliderImg";

        if((bodyWidth >= 415) && (bodyWidth < 473)){
            this.setState({responsiveImg: responsiveSliderImg});
            console.log("The state is : " + this.state.responsiveImg);
        }
    }
}
```

I'm trying to add a class name to the state in componentWillMount function, but it doesn't work. In console log I get **The state is :** , thus the state is empty.

Any idea?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

State doesn't update synchronously.  From the [docs](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-api.html)

> setState() does not immediately mutate this.state but creates a
>   pending state transition. Accessing this.state after calling this
>   method can potentially return the existing value.

Try checking the state in your render method.

It's also good to become aware of which of the lifecycle methods you can call setState in without a re-render occurring.  Can be helpful in some cases.  I use [reactcheatsheet](http://reactcheatsheet.com/) as a quick reference.  Click the "lifecycle" filter to see a very helpful table reference.

---

As a matter of interest.  I have developed a utility library to help with responsive use cases similar to yours.  It provides your component with the size of it's container allow you to do responsive render logic.  It could be helpful to you?  Check it out [here](https://github.com/ctrlplusb/react-sizeme).

Comment: I don't mind, you can accept the other answer.  It's best to select the answer that meets your needs the most.  It's good to select an answer for a question.

Answer (score 4):

[`setState`](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-api.html#setstate) is not immediately update state., if you need get new state you can pass callback as second argument to [`setState`](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-api.html#setstate)

```
this.setState({responsiveImg: responsiveSliderImg}, function () {
 // get new state here
});
```

[`Example`](https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/49864/)